# How to get committed item quantity on after submit event?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

i'm trying to get some value from sales order line item, but for some reason i cannot get quantity committed field from the sales order item.

This is the existing code that i'm using:

```
/**
* @NApiVersion 2.x
* @NScriptType UserEventScript 
*/
define([
  'N/log'
  ], function(
    log
  ) {
    const exports = {};
      function afterSubmit(context) {
      var newRecord = context.newRecord
      switch (context.type) {
        case context.UserEventType.CREATE:
          return ;
        case context.UserEventType.EDIT:
          var payload = getSalesOrderItems(newRecord);
          log.debug(payload);
          break;
        default:
          throw 'Invalid event type';
      }
  }

  exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit;
  return exports;
});

function getSalesOrderItems(salesRecord) 
      {
        var items = [];
        var itemLength = salesRecord.getLineCount({
            sublistId : 'item'
        }); 

        if (itemLength === 0) throw 'Order does not have any valid item';

        for (var index = 0; index < itemLength; index++) {
          var item = {};

          var itemId = salesRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item', 
            fieldId: 'item', 
            line: index
          });

          try {
            var itemRecord = record.load({
              type: record.Type.SERIALIZED_INVENTORY_ITEM,
              id: itemId,
            });
          } catch (ex) {
            if (JSON.parse(ex).name == "SSS_RECORD_TYPE_MISMATCH") {
              itemRecord = record.load({
                type: record.Type.KIT_ITEM,
                id: itemId,
              });
            }
          }

          if (!itemRecord) throw ('Item with id ' + itemId + ' does not exist');

          item.sku = itemRecord.getValue('itemidorig');
          item.quantity_committed = salesRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantitycommitted', line: index
          });
          item.quantity = salesRecord.getSublistValue({
            sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'quantity', line: index
          });

          items.push(item)

          return items;
        }
      }
```

this is the current result.

```
{
    [{
        "sku":"EMOST00405",
        "quantity":2
    }]
}
```

This is the result that i was expecting.

```
{
    [{
         "sku":"EMOST00405",
         "quantity_committed": 1,
         "quantity":2
    }]
}
```

It works fine when the event is triggered via update order. 
Any reply is appreciated.

Comment: Yo write that it works fine "when the event is triggered via update order". Does this mean in an after submit user event script? What is the context where it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct but NetSuite returns `undefined` if you don't have a field on **current form**(maybe hidden/not added on current form). Make sure to add and show the field on current SO form that you are working on and then try running the code again.